# Xamarin Forms static class references: multiple levels down

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

Referring to the concept of references to static variables/properties in Xamarin Forms xaml pages (https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/xaml_markup_extensions/); there is a section about references like this:

```
BackgroundColor="{x:Static local:AppConstants.ForegroundColor}"
```

...where local is a declared namespace, and AppConstants.ForegroundColor refers to a static property in a static class, like so:

```
namespace XamlSamples
{
    static class AppConstants
    {
        public static readonly Color ForegroundColor =
            Device.OnPlatform(Color.Black, Color.White, Color.White);

        ....
    }
}
```

My problem is, it doesn't seem to work if it goes another level down (not sure how to say this). For example, if I wanted to bind to:

```
SomeNumericalValue="{x:Static local:AppConstants.ForegroundColor.Hue}"
```

...it doesn't work: it throws a compilation error "Type AppConstants.ForegroundColor not found in xmlns 'namespacename...'". It doesn't seem to be able to go one more level in to access the 'Hue' property.

I don't understand, this works in WPF, but i can't find an equivalent way to do this in Xamarin Forms. Am I missing something? Is it because 'Hue' isn't static?

Comment: I think I just hit the solution: I have to add 'Binding' in front of 'x:Static'.

How or why it works though, I have no idea. The examples I've Googled don't seem to shed light on this. Anyway, hope it helps anyone who's hit the same problem...

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because the properties in your class are only accesible at runtime.

{StaticResource...  Fetches the values at compile time.

{Binding...  Does it at runtime, so you need to use this.

Comment: This is a helpful answer to add since it clarifies why the solution works. It would be even better if it included links to documentation that supports it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer shortly later: I replied to my own comment but I guess it's better to put it here.

The solution was to add 'Binding' at the very front:

```
SomeNumericalValue="{Binding x:Static local:AppConstants.ForegroundColor.Hue}"
```

How or why, I still don't  understand. Hope this helps anyone who encounters the same thing, but would also appreciate anyone who can explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure AppConstants is a public class.  In your code snippet above, it isn't which would lead to an error like you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah the class was public. Sorry was just using the tutorial's code as an example. My equivalent class was correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the `x:static` and just doing:

```
SomeNumericalValue="{local:AppConstants.ForegroundColor.Hue}"
```